# What screw to use with 1.8mm thick countersunk brackets?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I have a few brackets that are 1.8mm thick with 4.5mm countersunk holes [like this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32760951479.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000023.9.54c3301cdNyQzf):

[image]

The countersunk machine screws that I've found have head heights of at least 2.2mm (some 3.2mm). This is taken from https://www.mcmaster.com/screws

[image]

Anyone know what sort of countersunk screws should be used with these brackets? I can't seem to find any common ones with a head height of ~1.5mm.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you assume that the head needs to be flush with the surface? Countersunk screws are used as much for their self-centring behaviour as their low profile.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Do you mean the screw hole is meant to be countersunk?

Comment: No... I mean it’s not unusual for a countersunk screw to stick out above the surface you’re screwing it into. This is because there are good reasons to choose a countersunk screw *other* than it being (relatively) low profile

Comment: Length of screw is also determined by the material it is going into.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift But you can have both! Centering and flush. And why would you want the head sticking out?

Comment: @DDuck To better accommodate a standard drive such as a PH1. Oval Heads are much stronger and capable of taking a beefier Phillips or Square drive recess (even if nominal driver is the same). For slotted screws, you can use a wider driver too. Tiny slotted flatheads basically suck. See specs here for better explanation - https://www.aftfasteners.com/wood-screws-dimensions-mechanical-specs/ Compare allowable recess for #4 flat vs #4 oval

Comment: For the truly fastener anal - [undercut flathead machine screw](https://cdn10.bigcommerce.com/s-gdy1ehz/products/109561/images/114553/FlatHead-Snake-Machine__94179.1421788916.175.175.jpg?c=2)

Comment: @PhilSweet do consider some of us find metric “normal”....

Comment: Yes, they are normal. I just wasn't aware of a 90 degree countersink. That's probably a bad thing for a M.E. <shrug>.